# Hard blocked wifi Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

What is the work around available?

Comment: I am unable to connect to wifi, please help!

Comment: followed your thread and tried everything, now the output of rfkill is

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no but no luck as still getting error - no wireless network found

Comment: Please modify your original question and add the current status..

Comment: Where do I add current status of this message

Comment: [Click here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/588454/edit) and add to the end..

Comment: Have added a new question, please help - I have tried connecting to wifi in my dell vostro laptop, distribution is ubuntu 12.04 lts. Wicd network manager shows "No wireless networks found."

Comment: So after following the link the original issue has been resolved? (As you have marked it as 'solved')

Comment: Yes the original issue is solved but wifi aint working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enter this in the terminal:

```
 rfkill unblock hard
```

and that it is, and it might work fine this way.